# How to create and test in app store items

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, titanium-mobile

I am using titanium to create my app, the problem that I am having is that I am not able to retrieve the products after creating them in itunes connect

```
InAppProducts.addEventListener('receivedProducts', function(e) {
    if (e.errorCode) {
        alert('Error: getProducts call failed! Message: ' + e.errorMessage);
    } else {
        Ti.API.info('getProducts succeeded!');

        productObjects = e.products;
        alert(productObjects);
        Ti.API.info('Product count: ' + productObjects.length);

    }

});
```

e.products returns 0. My application is not live on the app store,so I am unable to submit the product for review, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons your products might not get retrieved by your application:

- You are testing from a simulator. In-app purchase testing will only work from an actual device.
- Your application is not signed with the proper credentials, that is the certificate and keys for your own app. It will fail if you try with sign it with a wildcard certificate. Be sure to use a "Development" Provisioning Profile and an "App ID" with "In-App Purchase" enabled.
- You haven't setup properly the in-app purchase module. Environment, shared secret, receipt verification sandbox env,...
- You have not copied Apple's Root Certificate to the resources folder
- You have not logged out from your itunes account on your device. You should log out and use the test account generated in itunesConnect. But don't log in on the settings app, do it when your app prompts for credentials.

As for your code: if you are using ti.storekit module, there is no event called `'receivedProducts'` for the storekit object, so that must a wrapper of your own. If not, that might be your problem.

For further information check https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.storekit/blob/master/ios/example/app.js